# Running a Google Script from a duplicated speadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a Google spreadsheet that includes some basic script which emails someone when a task to which they are assigned comes due. The script works on the original sheet but when I duplicate the sheet and change nothing but the dates the script no longer works.

I'm not receiving any errors, the emails simply are not being sent.

I'm very new to Google script and wasn't able to find a good answer for this. Does anybody know what the issue might be?

Thanks so much!

```
    function myFunction() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    var FormattedTodayDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-0600','MM/dd/yyyy')

    //Here we get all the spreadsheets from the spreadsheet app
    var spreadSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //Here we pick out the first spreadsheet. 0 is the first tab of the spreadsheet "Active Sheet"
    var currentSheet = spreadSheets.getSheets()[0];


   //Here we set up where on the sheet we want to get the data
   var startRow = 3;
   var numRows = currentSheet.getLastRow()-1;
   var numCols = currentSheet.getLastColumn();

   //We use those numbers to find a range throughout the table (A2 - H* etc) where we want to grab the data from
   var dataRange = currentSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numCols);

   //Using the data range, grab all the values
   var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for(i in data){
  var row = data[i];
  var reminderDate = new Date(row[1]);
  var dueDate = new Date(row[3]);
  var FormattedReminderDate = Utilities.formatDate(reminderDate,'GMT-0600', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  var FormattedDueDate = Utilities.formatDate(dueDate,'GMT-0600', 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  if(row[0] === ''){

  //      Logger.log(FormattedTodayDate);
  //      
  //      Logger.log(FormattedReminderDate);
  //      
  //      Logger.log(FormattedReminderDate == FormattedTodayDate);

  if(FormattedReminderDate == FormattedTodayDate){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: row[7],
        subject: row[4] + " task due on " + FormattedDueDate,
        htmlBody: "The following " + row[4] + " task is coming due on <b>" + FormattedDueDate + "</b> : <br/> <br>" + row[5] + "<br> </br>Go to Google Spreadsheet for more details: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jIBX5By1jhro1V-gHXPPlhIOXDLut6CMvaq92uW5bFw/edit#gid=0&range=" + row[8] + "<br/><br> Please remember to add the word 'done' to the 'done?' column when you complete this task.",
      })
  }
  if(FormattedDueDate == FormattedTodayDate){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: row[7],
        subject: row[4] + " task due TODAY",
        htmlBody: "The following " + row[4] + " task has not been completed and is due TODAY: <br/> <br>" + row[5] + "<br> </br>Go to Google Spreadsheet for more details: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jIBX5By1jhro1V-gHXPPlhIOXDLut6CMvaq92uW5bFw/edit#gid=0&range=" + row[8] + "<br/><br> Please remember to add the word 'done' to the 'done?' column when you complete this task.",
      })
  }

} 
}
}
```

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any obvious reason it should not work. Can you edit the question to explain how you are running the function, how you know it's not working, and what errors (if any) you are receiving?

Comment: Thanks @Cameron-Roberts I've updated the question

Comment: Try View/Executions

Comment: Thanks @Cooper View/Executions shows 'completed' and no errors. I've created a 'test' task for today that should have triggered an email but unfortunately nothing is being sent.

Comment: Well sounds like it's time to step through the script with the debugger and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Cooper the debugger runs for just a moment, empty boxes briefly appear in the bottom of the screen, then disappear without any message. The screen returns to the script view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. Turns out this issue was caused by our spam filter blocking the notifications.